# Return in function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function, loops, return, javascript-objects

I wrote a function which compares two objects whether the are equal.
Why does my return statement in the loop not work?

```js
var deepEqual = function(a, b){
  var aProp = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
  var bProp = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);
  if(aProp.length !== bProp.length){
   return false;
  }
  else{
   for (var i = 0; i < aProp.length; i++) {
    if(typeof a[aProp[i]] === 'object' && typeof b[bProp[i]] === 'object'){
     deepEqual(a[aProp[i]], b[bProp[i]]);
    }
    else{
     if(a[aProp[i]] !== b[bProp[i]]){
      return false; // WHY IT DOESN'T WORK???
     }
    }
   };
   return true;
  }
 };

 var obj = {a: 2, here: {is: "asn"}, object: 2, d: 12};
 console.log(deepEqual(obj, {a: 2, here: {is: "an"}, object: 2, d: 12}));
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not doing anything with the recursive call to `deepEqual`.

You can check its result, and return false if there's no match:

```js
var deepEqual = function(a, b){
  var aProp = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
  var bProp = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);
  if(aProp.length !== bProp.length){
    return false;
  }
  else {
    for (var i = 0; i < aProp.length; i++) {
      if(typeof a[aProp[i]] === 'object' && typeof b[bProp[i]] === 'object'){
        if(!deepEqual(a[aProp[i]], b[bProp[i]])) { //<- changed
          return false;
        }
      }
      else {
        if(a[aProp[i]] !== b[bProp[i]]){
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
};

var obj = {a: 2, here: {is: "asn"}, object: 2, d: 12};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {a: 2, here: {is: "an"}, object: 2, d: 12}));  //false
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using recursion but not checking to see if a recursive call has failed. Try this instead:

```
    if (!deepEqual(a[aProp[i]], b[bProp[i]])) {
        return false;
    }
```